# How to display a JPEG on ANativeWindow?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, libjpeg-turbo, turbojpeg

I am trying to show a JPEG to a ANativeWindow with the Android NDK.
I am getting the `ANativeWindow*` by doing:

```
_window = ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env, surface)
```

I am loading the jpeg, with libjpeg-turbo, by doing:

```
if (tjDecompressHeader2(tj, jpeg, jpegSize, &width, &height, &subsamp) == 0) {
    int format = TJPF_ARGB;
    int pitch  = _windowWidth * tjPixelSize[format];

    _bufferSize = pitch * _windowHeight;
    _buffer = realloc(_buffer, _bufferSize);
    tjDecompress2(tj, jpeg, jpegSize, _buffer, _windowWidth, pitch, _windowHeight, format, 0);
}
```

My Question is, how to show the decoded jpeg on the surface ? I am currently doing this:

```
ANativeWindow_Buffer surface_buffer;
if (ANativeWindow_lock(_window, &surface_buffer, NULL) == 0) {
    memcpy(surface_buffer.bits, _buffer,  _bufferSize);
    ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost(_window);
}
```

But the result (see below) is not what I was expecting. What should I do before sending the buffer to the surface ?

[image: snapshot]

Thanks

Comment: Can you give more detail about what the result was?

Comment: I added a snapshot to the question of what is the current result.

Comment: it might be the window format. I noticed your decoding to ARGB, it looks like the supported window formats are: WINDOW_FORMAT_RGBA_8888, WINDOW_FORMAT_RGBX_8888, WINDOW_FORMAT_RGB_565

Comment: Thanks, I already tried to change the decompress format but never tried to set the ANativeWindow's one with ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry().

Comment: No problem! I guess I should have made my suggestion an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just need to set ANativeWindow's format with `ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(_window, 0, 0, WINDOW_FORMAT_RGBA_8888)`. And then use `TJPF_RGBA` format instead of `TJPF_ARGB`.